# How To Wrap Multiple Content Field Items In Li Tag

Tags: theming, 8

I've got an issue with a field called Track Listing. As the title states it is a Text(plain) type with unlimited possible values so that I can input as many as I'd like. The machine name is: track_listing

As it stands I'm outputting the label and items using: `{{ content.field_track_listing }}` which gives me this:

[image: Track Listing]

But I'd like to be able to wrap the field in an **ol** tag in addition to every track with a **li** tag to be able to get a nice ordered numbered list. Using twig templates I've wrapped it accordingly but find it only targets the first value which is in this case the label as seen here:

[image: track listing ordered list]

I feel that I should be using a for/if loop in order to get the right values since removing the label only wraps the first item as well. If anyone has an article I can check out to point myself in the right direction I would appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily theme a multiple value field in the field template.

To do this put a field twig in `mytheme/templates`:

**field--field-track-listing.html.twig**

```
<div{{ attributes }}>

  <div{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</div>

  <ol>
  {% for item in items %}
    <li>{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>

</div>
```

Here you can change the html markup around each field item `{{ item.content }}` the same way as you do this in node around the complete field `{{ content.field_name }}`. This is the concept of nested render elements.

Answer (score 2):

Inside **node--[content-type-name].html.twig**

```
<ol>

{% for track in content.field_track_listing['#items'].getValue() %}

  <li>{{ track.value }}</li>

{% endfor %}

</ol>
```

If you need to display the field label, put `{{ content.field_track_listing['#title'] }}` before the `<ol>` tag